# jQuery $(window).resize not firing within jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery

I've created a custom jQuery plugin and having issues getting the window resize function to fire within the plugin. Broke it down to the basics of what I got, can't figure out why it's not firing:

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  $.fn.test = function(options) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      alert('sdsd');
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('.element').test();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case `window` is undefined because you aren't passing it into the function.

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {
  $.fn.test = function(options) {
    $(window).resize(function() {
      alert('sdsd');
    });
  };
})(jQuery, window, document); //<--- changes here
```

Comment: Awesome, its always the simple things isnt it. Thanks! ill check the answer as soon as it lets me