# Jquery Plugin: how use window resize?

Tags: jquery

Looking for create my very first Jquery Plugin.
Basically center vertically a div in a blank page.

```
    (function($){  
    $.fn.centerdiv = function(options) {  
        var defaults = {  
            ratio   :   2
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        // get some useful variables
        var $this           = $(this);
        var $heightDiv      = $this.height();
        var $heightWindow   = $(window).height();
        var $marginTop      = Math.round(($heightWindow - $heightDiv)/options.ratio);
        var applyMargin     = function() {
            $this.css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
            console.log($heightWindow);
        }
        $(window).resize(applyMargin);
        applyMargin();
        return $this;
    }; // fn.centerdiv
})(jQuery);
```

It works but not for the "window resize". Found another answer ( [jQuery $(window).resize not firing within jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15645347/jquery-window-resize-not-firing-within-jquery-plugin) ) but adding "window" after `$` does not solve my problem. How i can have this plugin working also with window resize? Thank you to all!

Edited with answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` in the context of your `window.resize` event handler refers to `window`. You should store a reference to the outer `this` so you can use it within the event handler:

```
...
var $this = $(this);
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $this.css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
    });
...
```

You also need to place your `return` at the end of the function, everything after it does not execute.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here

- that you're applying the css to the `window`.
- that part of your code is after the `return` statement.

Replace

```
return this.each(function() {
     $(this).css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
}); // return
$(window).resize(function() {
     $(this).css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
});
```

with

```
var $this = $(this), f = function(){
    $this.css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
}
$(window).resize(f);
f();
return $this;
```

and put that before the `return` statement.

Comment: Edited code with your answer, but it doesn't resize with window. Did i make some other mistake? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Solved: i did not re-calculate height of window. This is final code. Do you think is it right?

```
(function($){  
    $.fn.centerdiv = function(options) {  
        var defaults = {  
            ratio   :   2
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        // get some useful variables
        var $this           = $(this);
        var calculateMargin = function() {
            var $heightDiv      = $this.height();
            var $heightWindow   = $(window).height();
            var $marginTop      = Math.round(($heightWindow - $heightDiv)/options.ratio);
            return $marginTop;  
        }
        return this.each(function() {
            var $marginTop = calculateMargin();
            $this.css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
            $(window).resize(function() {
                var $marginTop = calculateMargin();
                $this.css('margin-top',$marginTop+'px');
            });
        }); 
    }; // fn.centerdiv
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: You are doing more work than necessary. You're caching `$(this)` as `$this`, which can contain multiple elements. And then you're binding a `window.resize` event handler for every event, but inside that event handler you're applying CSS to all elements in the `$this` object. I'd either create the `$this` variable within the `.each()` loop or bind to `window.resize` only once. Also, generally starting a variable with `$` in a project that uses jQuery signifies that the variable is a jQuery object.

Comment: Thnak you for your feedback. I would learn,so could you write changes to improve this micro plugin? Thank you